# Javasacript get the timezone name string?

Tags: javascript, timezone

How we can get the timezone strgin name from javascript, for example

```
var d = new Date();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =d;
```

this returns

> Thu Mar 30 2017 15:13:57 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)

Now how we can get the part between the brackets(Pakistan Standard Time) ?

Comment: an ugly way is to subtring `indexOf('(')` up to the end

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like

`/\((.*)\)/.exec(new Date().toString())[1];`

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.toLocaleString('en', {timeZoneName:'long'}).split(' ');
var index = n.length;
do {
    index--;
    console
} while(n[index] !== "PM" && n[index] !== "AM");
var timezone = n.slice(index+1).join(" ");
console.log(timezone);
```